# AutoComplete does not work when I use VS code with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I work with unity and the VS code autocomplete does not complete many unity objects and more..
I have 2 extensions on my VS:
1.C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp).
2.Unity Code Snippets.
I'm using windows 10 and I looking for answers on the web for weeks, I tried to play with the settings, open new projects, reinstall VS CODE and nothing happen.
also I saw that it's happen mostly to people with an old version of Unity but it's not my case..

I work with unity version 2021.1.15f1 personal and VSCODE 1.59.1

This is a picture that illustrates the situation
[image]

Comment: I had same problem with Unity 2019.4 and I installed .net4.8 and it is solved.

Comment: @BarışCanYılmaz thank you for your answer, Unfortunately .net4.8 is already installed on my computer and it's not working..

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't find an answer for this issue, so I work with VS 2022 and it's much better

Answer (score 4):

Apologies if you've tried everything there already, but following the instructions at this link have helped me get auto-complete for Unity set up in VS Code when I got started: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

One key aspect that I had missed originally was the **Unity Script Editor set up section.** IntelliSense only starts working after you have **opened a script via the Unity Editor** rather than straight in VS Code. It generates an Assembly-CSharp.csproj file at the root which is necessary for enabling the functionality.

Comment: unfortunately I try everything without success. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I had the same issue and found a fix. I already implemented all of the steps listed in this post to no prevail.

I want to post my fix so that this may be able to help others.

**My Solution:**

- I have a project using 202.3.48f1 (autocomplete worked fine).
- I started a new project with 2021.3.32f1 and autocomplete did not work.
- I searched for an answer but nothing worked.

Out of curiosity, I then closed out of the project that autocomplete wasn't working in, then opened up the other project where autocomplete was working to see if it was still working, and it was indeed working.

I then opened up my non-working project and bam, autocomplete started working.

All I had to do was open a different working project for the autocomplete to work again.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Visual Studio Code is selected as the default "External Script Editor" in your Unity preferences.

To do that in Unity, go to Edit->Preferences and then select "Visual Studio Code" as your preferred external script editor. Restart VSC afterwards.

Comment: it was selected of course.

Comment: Did AutoComplete ever work for you before?

Comment: yes it was indeed

Comment: I will share what my current setup is and hopefully that can help you replicate an environment where VS Code auto complete functionality works:  Unity version (2020.3.16f1) - .NET Framework dev. package version (4.7.1) - VS Community 2019 (with additional Windows SDK 10.0.16299.0) - VS Code version (1.68.1) - VS Code Extensions (C# for Visual Studio Code). On Omnisharp server startup, it locates MSBuild instance: .NET Core SDK 6.0.202 17.1.1 . You should also try to regenerate you Unity project files (Edit->Preferences->External Tools)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I found an answer for how to fix it after searching for ages.

Firstly, here's a link for a video explaining how to fix it:
https://youtu.be/ihVAKiJdd40

what made it work for me was after going to edit-> preferences -> external tools and unchecking embedded packages and local packages, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my Visual Studio Editor version to 2.0.20. then I restart my script from unity, and it worked.
Hope this video helps you:
https://vionixstudio.com/2021/11/02/unity-visual-studio-code/#For_Unity_2021_or_newer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).